# Timespan in a dispatcherTimer

Tags: c#, wpf, timer, timespan, dispatchertimer

I'm programing a WPF application in VS C# 2010 and I'm programming a simulation. This simulation can be either run automatically (by pressing the Auto button) or step by step (clicking the Step button). However, what I want to implement is a speed control.

I have designed a simple comboBox with 4 possible items (1,2,5,10), which represent the simulation speed. Here is the code I'm using:

```
private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int speed = Int32.Parse(comboBox1.Text.ToString());
        dispathcerTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
        dispathcerTimer.Tick +=new EventHandler(dispatcherTimer_Tick);
        dispathcerTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, Convert.ToInt32(1000/speed));
        dispathcerTimer.Start();
    }
```

What this is supposed to do is to take the value selected in the comboBox and since TimeSpan does not accept double, just Int32, I must use the 4th parameter, miliseconds. I thought that doing 1000/speed would work but it does absolutely not, the time is even bigger. How can I change the time interval, for example, to reduce it from just 1 second (default at x1 Speed) to every 200 ms when the user selects the x5 Option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a wrong overload of `TimeSpan`, the fourth argument is actually for `second` (the first is for `day`). Try this simple static method `TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds` instead:

```
dispathcerTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000/speed);
```